# how to handle null values using ternary condition on Serverside datatable script on php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have to use data table with server side scripting. i have met problem when i have null value in database for particular field. I need to show '-' instead of null value then corresponding value from db if not null.my particular line is

```
  array('db' => 'custname',
       'dt' => 2,
       'formatter' => function($d,$row) {
        return($d == '')?'-': 'db' => 'custname';
       })
```

in fixed condition i have used similar without db values its worked. like,

```
array('db' => 'status',
       'dt' => 4,
       'formatter' => function($d,$row) {
        return($d == 'a')?'Active':'Hold';
       })
```

But when i need db value if data not null i have struggled.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
array('db' => 'custname',
   'dt' => 2,
   'formatter' => function($d,$row) {
    return(!isset($d))?'-': $d;
   })
```

updated answer because empty would return true for more cases than only null

Comment: `empty()` will return true in more situations than null.

Comment: i have updated answer thanks @MagnusEriksson

Comment: `isset()` will do the job just fine. I would probably do `$d === null` though, since it would be more clear what the condition is when others (or even you, a few months from now) looks at the code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i thought it would be relevant to show '  ' (blank data) that's why i suggested isset().